# Can more than 5 votes be cast to close a question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, vote-to-close, voting-anomaly-detection

The [Stackoverflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) for voting a `closed question` states

> Users with 3000 reputation can cast up to 50 close votes per day. When
>   a question reaches 5 close votes, it is marked as closed, and will no
>   longer accept answers.

Another [question on Meta Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/214223) adds that `Moderators may close any question (regardless of their reputation)`. This implies that a question on Stackoverflow may not receive more than 5 votes to be marked as `closed`. However, I see a few posts which have more than 5 `close` votes. Here is a list of some questions (there are 17 such questions according to the August 2012 snapshot) which have more than 5 `close` votes on it-

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2923424/revisions

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2917166/revisions

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2916277/revisions

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8411348/revisions

Is this an anomaly or am I missing something?

Comment: There are a few of these hanging around due to various bugs that've existed in the past. Of course, it's also possible for a question to receive more than 5 close votes if it gets re-opened...

Comment: Thanks for confirming it's a "bug". I do understand that >5 votes may be allowed if it is reopened but my understanding says that it will be a different instance which is clearly marked out.

Comment: Marking as [meta-tag:status-completed] as the original bug has been resolved.